# Load a .csv dataset from UCI ML repo

Tags: r

I am trying to load a dataset from UC Irvine ML repository in R but the link is for a zip folder within which are the .csv files.

this is the link to their zip files: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/759/glioma+grading+clinical+and+mutation+features+dataset.zip

```r
library(readr)

url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/759/glioma+grading+clinical+and+mutation+features+dataset.zip"

dataset <- read.csv(url)
```

I am not sure what to do next

I expect to load dataset into R enviroment directly from the link without loading from my local machine and to be extracted from the zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readr` function is called `read_csv`, `read.csv` (with a dot) is from base R. And`readr::read_csv()` by itself can't open remote zip archives:

```r
readr::read_csv(url_)
#> Error: Reading from remote `zip` compressed files is not supported,
#>   download the files locally first.
```

Though you can include `archive` to the mix. That zip includes multiple files, `archive::archive_read()` allows you select the correct one, either by name or index:

```r
library(readr)
library(archive)
url_ <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/static/public/759/glioma+grading+clinical+and+mutation+features+dataset.zip"

csv_1 <- read_csv(archive_read(url_, 1))
#> Rows: 862 Columns: 27
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (27): Grade, Project, Case_ID, Gender, Age_at_diagnosis, Primary_Diagnos...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
dplyr::glimpse(csv_1)
#> Rows: 862
#> Columns: 27
#> $ Grade             <chr> "LGG", "LGG", "LGG", "LGG", "LGG", "LGG", "LGG", "LG…
#> $ Project           <chr> "TCGA-LGG", "TCGA-LGG", "TCGA-LGG", "TCGA-LGG", "TCG…
#> $ Case_ID           <chr> "TCGA-DU-8164", "TCGA-QH-A6CY", "TCGA-HW-A5KM", "TCG…
#> $ Gender            <chr> "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", …
#> $ Age_at_diagnosis  <chr> "51 years 108 days", "38 years 261 days", "35 years …
#> $ Primary_Diagnosis <chr> "Oligodendroglioma, NOS", "Mixed glioma", "Astrocyto…
#> $ Race              <chr> "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white"…
#> $ IDH1              <chr> "MUTATED", "MUTATED", "MUTATED", "MUTATED", "MUTATED…
#> $ TP53              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATED", "MUTATED", …
#> $ ATRX              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATED", "MUTATED", …
#> $ PTEN              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ EGFR              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ CIC               <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATE…
#> $ MUC16             <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATE…
#> $ PIK3CA            <chr> "MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATE…
#> $ NF1               <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ PIK3R1            <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATE…
#> $ FUBP1             <chr> "MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATE…
#> $ RB1               <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ NOTCH1            <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ BCOR              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ CSMD3             <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ SMARCA4           <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ GRIN2A            <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ IDH2              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…
#> $ FAT4              <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "MUTATE…
#> $ PDGFRA            <chr> "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MUTATED", "NOT_MU…

csv_2 <- read_csv(archive_read(url_, 2))
#> Rows: 839 Columns: 24
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> dbl (24): Grade, Gender, Age_at_diagnosis, Race, IDH1, TP53, ATRX, PTEN, EGF...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
dplyr::glimpse(csv_2)
#> Rows: 839
#> Columns: 24
#> $ Grade            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ Gender           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ Age_at_diagnosis <dbl> 51.30, 38.72, 35.17, 32.78, 31.51, 33.21, 35.19, 44.6…
#> $ Race             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ IDH1             <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ TP53             <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ ATRX             <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,…
#> $ PTEN             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ EGFR             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ CIC              <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ MUC16            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ PIK3CA           <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,…
#> $ NF1              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ PIK3R1           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ FUBP1            <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ RB1              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ NOTCH1           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ BCOR             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ CSMD3            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ SMARCA4          <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ GRIN2A           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ IDH2             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ FAT4             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ PDGFRA           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>