# read.csv error, can't separate the first row

Tags: r, read.csv

Tried to import a csv file in the zip file from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/697/predict+students+dropout+and+academic+success

using

> df.raw=read.csv("data.csv",sep=";")

but it keeps returning the error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> more columns than column names

I've tried

> df.raw=read.csv("data.csv",sep=";",header = FALSE)

but it just returns the first row as

> "Marital status;Application mode;Application order;Course;"Daytime/evening attendance\t";Previous qualification;Previous qualification (grade);Nacionality;Mother's qualification;Father's qualification;Mother's occupation;Father's occupation;Admission grade;Displaced;Educational special needs;Debtor;Tuition fees up to date;Gender;Scholarship holder;Age at enrollment;International;Curricular units 1st sem (credited);Curricular units 1st sem (enrolled);Curricular units 1st sem (evaluations);Curricular units 1st sem (approved);Curricular units 1st sem (grade);Curricular units 1st sem (without evaluations);Curricular units 2nd sem (credited);Curricular units 2nd sem (enrolled);Curricular units 2nd sem (evaluations);Curricular units 2nd sem (approved);Curricular units 2nd sem (grade);Curricular units 2nd sem (without evaluations);Unemployment rate;Inflation rate;GDP;Target;"

As one singular cell of data

Comment: I can't reproduce the first error. Have you opened and perhaps (auto-)saved that in a text editor or Excel? Can you open it directly from zip to be sure something has not tampered with the file? E.g. `read.csv2(unz("predict+students+dropout+and+academic+success.zip", "data.csv"))` or `readr::read_csv2("predict+students+dropout+and+academic+success.zip")` .  Somewhat relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76800932/load-a-csv-dataset-from-uci-ml-repo

Answer (score 1):

I checked you issue, but I'm unfortunately unable to reproduce your error, as your data and code are running smooth on my side (using R version 4.2.1).

However I guess that your problem might come from the extra quotes on the "Daytime/evening attendance\t" column name from the csv.file, which lead your version of R to mishandle the column names ?
I don't have a best answer than try to to remove/change that directly in the csv file, as I can't reproduce your issue.

Best luck !